# fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes (using gamekit)

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit

Using GameKit Multiplayer feature (EasyGameCenter) found here: https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Easy-Game-Center-Swift

Upon two players connecting I get a crash on this line

```
let playerIDs = match.players.map { $0 .playerID } as! [String]
```

With this in console

> fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes

Any ideas? Here is full function for easy reference:

```
 @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    private func lookupPlayers() {

        guard let match =  EGC.sharedInstance.match else {
            EGC.printLogEGC("No Match")
            return
        }

        let playerIDs = match.players.map { $0 .playerID } as! [String]

        /* Load an array of player */
        GKPlayer.loadPlayersForIdentifiers(playerIDs) {
            (players, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                EGC.printLogEGC("Error retrieving player info: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                EGC.disconnectMatch()
                return
            }

            guard let players = players else {
                EGC.printLogEGC("Error retrieving players; returned nil")
                return
            }
            if EGC.debugMode {
                for player in players {
                    EGC.printLogEGC("Found player: \(player.alias)")
                }
            }

            if let arrayPlayers = players as [GKPlayer]? { self.playersInMatch = Set(arrayPlayers) }

            GKMatchmaker.sharedMatchmaker().finishMatchmakingForMatch(match)
            (Static.delegate as? EGCDelegate)?.EGCMatchStarted?()

        }
    }
```

Comment: What if you split that line into two lines.  Store the value of the map to a temp variable on one line, and then cast it to `[String]` on the next line.  Do you still see the same issue?

Comment: Not sure how I would do that, new to swift. This code is right from the EasyGameCenter github

Comment: `let tempPlayerIDs = match.players.map { $0 .playerID }` followed by `let playerIDs = tempPlayerIDs as! [String]`

Comment: Unfortunately, still happens, now on the let playerIDs line.

Comment: It looks like playerID is a String? type, so what if you change `match.players.map { $0.playerID }` to `match.players.map { $0.playerID! }`

Comment: Great seemed to get rid of that error thank you, but unfortunately back to "plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension invalidated" .. seems others have that issue with iOS9 as well though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `map` statement is resulting in a type of `Array<String?>` because `playerID` is a `String?`, which you can't cast directly to `Array<String>`.

If you're certain you will always have a `playerID` value, you could change the statement

```
match.players.map { $0.playerID }
```

to:

```
match.players.map { $0.playerID! }
```

If you're not certain of that, then you can either use the `Array<String?>` value with appropriate optional handling or strip out the `nil` values by switching from `map` to `flatMap`:

```
match.players.flatMap { $0.playerID }
```